# Protobuf deserializing works on one dev machine but not another

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

I develop a C# application for the company I work for. Some data objects are serialized using protocol buffers. I am now working on deserializing these objects in a Java application the company also develops. On my dev machine everything works. However if I try to run my test project on a different machine things fail. Some members are not being populated with values.

Is there some Protobuf dependency that I'm not aware of? I am getting the Protobuf.jar file by compiling the 2.3.0 source.

I can send my test project if needed.

Edit:

Not sure what I did but my test project is now working. However, when I add the files to the application's project I get "com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: Protocol message tag had invalid wire type."

What could possibly be different that would cause this exception?

Resolve:

The file I was trying to deserialize got corrupted when I copied it into the main projects unit test. All I had to do was delete the file and replace it with the version I knew was working. SUCCESS!

Comment: I suspect a repeatable example would be necessary - but simple things: are you *sure* they are using the same .proto source; and are they both using the same pb version? (the wire format etc is meant to be identical, but occasionally bugs happen)

Comment: On the Java side, the .proto was compiled by me and the resulting .java files is what is being used in the test app. Oh and, I've sent you the test project.

Comment: I sent the email address in your profile, but it just got bounced back to me.

Comment: I assume from the way you've asked your question that you don't get any exceptions?

Comment: @Rich - Originally (test project) I was getting no exception, just bad values. Now I get an exception. Please see edit to the question.

Comment: Seen the edit - looking; that *generally* means something like accidentally overwriting a file without truncating it; where (code-wise) is the file written?